# reloading singleton classes and dependency

Tags: design-patterns, object-oriented, web-applications, object-oriented-design

I have a singleton object.  It's a DAO that looks somewhat like this (pseudoish code):

```
class UsersDAO {
  public usersDAO init(string sDSN){
    variables.sDSN = sDSN;

    return this;
  }

  public array getUsers(){
    //do a query to get users, make into array

    return aUsers;
  }
}
```

my applications makes an instance of this and uses it throughout the codebase, but I also have another DAO that requires it:

```
class OrganisationsDAO {
  public OrganisationsDAO init(UsersDAO oUsersDAO,string sDSN){
     variables.sDSN = sDSN;
     variables.oUsersDAO = oUsersDAO;

     return this;
  }

  public array getUsersOrganisations(){
    variables.aUsers = variables.oUsersDAO.getUsers();

    //getOrganisations for the returned users

    return aOrganisations;
  }
}
```

so to make the OrganisationsDAO object I need to pass it the UsersDAO.

At a later point in my applications life, I need to update the UsersDAO to include a `public user getUser(int userid)` function.

I'm wondering, is there a way of passing through the new UsersDAO to objects that depend on it, without having to restart the application.  In this instance the application is a website rather than a desktop based application.

Comment: Why is there a software requirement that states that a method should only be visible to the rest of the code during a certain part of the application's lifetime?  Couldn't you simply throw an exception in the method if it is not yet time to call it?

Comment: sorry @RobertHarvey i'm not 100% sure what you mean. it's not a requirement, it's just a natural progression.  Let's say the `UsersDAO` was written 100days a go and had no need to change, then we suddenly needed a new function that it didn't already have, i update the file and deploy it.  If i don't restart the application, the change won't be noticed and thus the function unusable. the only way to use the new functionality is to restart the application.  does that clarify any more?

Comment: @Jarede what web server/platform are you running on ? You might want to be more specific here.

Comment: @guillaume31 i'm running it on Coldfusion (JVM based)... though i was hoping for a more general design pattern or principle when tackling this as it might/could be a problem for other languages

Comment: I guess the general principle is to place `UsersDAO` in a separate deployment unit from the start. Then redeploy it when it has changed and pray that your web server is able to refresh dependencies without restarting the app ;)

Comment: Oh, sorry.  By lifetime, I thought you meant the run time, i.e. execution of the program.

Answer (score 1):

Don't pass an object to the client classes. Pass a function that gives them the object they need (a factory, a provider). Convince them that calling this function is cheap, because it immediately returns a cached value when possible, so that they don't keep their own long-lived cached values.

Do away with `variables.oUserDao` and replace it with some `variables.oUserDaoProvider`. Then something like`variables.oUserDaoProvider.getDao().getUsers()` allows you to control what `getDao()` returns from the outside, while your clients always get the correct DAO.